# MongoDB upsert array document with golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a document like below：

```
 {
       "_id": "1.0",
        files: [
          {"name": "file_1", "size": 1024, "create_ts": 1570862776426},
          {"name": "file_2", "size": 2048, "create_ts": 1570862778426}
        ]
    }
```

And I want to upsert “files” with "file_x"：
1 if "file_x" already in "files", then update, for example "file_x" is：

```
{"name": "file_2", "size": 4096, "create_ts": 1570862779426}
```

after upsert document is：

```
{
   "_id": "1.0",
    files: [
      {"name": "file_1", "size": 1024, "create_ts": 1570862776426},
      {"name": "file_2", "size": 4096, "create_ts": 1570862779426}}
    ]
}
```

2 if "file_x" not in "files",  insert it， for example "file_x" is：

```
{"name": "file_3", "size": 4096, "create_ts": 1570862779426}
```

after upsert document is :

```
{
   "_id": "1.0",
    files: [
      {"name": "file_1", "size": 1024, "create_ts": 1570862776426},
      {"name": "file_2", "size": 2048, "create_ts": 1570862778426},
      {"name": "file_3", "size": 4096, "create_ts": 1570862779426}
    ]
}
```

So can I use one function to archive it ?

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too - despite its "harsh" title. Please add a [mcve] to your question [by editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58353030/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do this manually. There's no upsert mechanism for embedded structures inside a document.

First fetch the document, check if `file_x` is in the files list, if not, insert it. Then save the document back.

You should make sure that at any given time, only one program / goroutine is trying to do this, otherwise you will run into race conditions and `file_x` might get inserted multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single update operation in mongodb update language that will do what you want to do. You can get close by using `$addToSet`, which adds to a set of items if the item is not already there, but it will not update the item based on the match of a subset of fields. Your best option is to perform a read-update in memory-write.